# How to Calculate Change in Temperature Relative to Distance from a Heat Source

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-transfer, heating-systems

Just as the title suggests. I have recently conducted model human ear canal using a heated reservoir (water at consistent temperature) with silicone rubber tubing of all known geometric features. Many assumptions can be made--however I am stuck on were to begin.

I have temperature measurements at 4 positions : 6mm, 12 mmm, 18mm and 24mm. I need to know what the average change in temperature per 1 mm away from the heat source.

Comment: So calculate heat losses due to conduction, convection and radiation.

Comment: Heat equation, unfortunately.

Comment: For this kind of stuff, I suggest starting at thermal conductivity of your materials.  Just modeling conduction to fit the measurements you have should give you an idea.